# Install GlassFish on FreeBSD shared server

Tags: java, glassfish, freebsd

**I asked this on superuser as well, but with no answers (even no views). If it's wrong to mention it here, please let me know or just move it. Thanks.**

We are using a shared server (six people with root access for each user), which is reinstalled and -configured soon. I agreed to install GlassFish for everyone to use. However, I am developer and do only know basiscs of Unix/Linux.

Now my question is, what do I have to consider if I want to meet these requirements:

Automatic startup on reboot (did not happen often in the past)
Easy integration with Apache
Usage of existing MySQL/PostgresSQL instance
Patterns/Tools for easy (shared) usage (installation of Java EE apps, administration)
Patterns/Tools for easy (shared) monitoring (resources (mem, db), applications)
Tools for easing remote development (EJB/WAR deployment, JRebel?)
Of course, there might be other topics I forgot which should be addressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Automatic start up under FreeBSD can simply be implemented using a start-up script which should just do 'asadmin start-domain' to start glassfish and 'asadmin stop-domain'. I'm sure there's a number of articles on start-up script creation for your version of FreeBSD (I would check FreeBSD Handbook first).
As to remote deployments - you just need a local copy of glassfish and should use it's asadmin utility - it has command line arguments that allow doing any administrative tasks with remote glassfish installations as long as you have admin password on them.

Answer (score 0):

If you have experience with Windows only then I would strongly consider using a Windows box for this.  The Glassfish distribution has functionality to register a given domain as a service, and I would suggest that you just create a domain for each developer.